# Font Not Showing Up?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm almost 100% sure what I'm doing is exactly correct Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <p>THE BIG BLUE SITE OF SAILING KNOWLEDGE</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face: {font-family: "ostrich-reg"; src: url('Fonts/ostrich-regular-webfont.ttf'); }
@font-face: {font-family: "ostrich-light"; src: url("Fonts/ostrich-light.ttf"); }
@font-face: {font-family: "collab"; src: url("Fonts/ColabThi.otf"); }

#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 27%;
    background: #2d5dac;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu p {
    color: white;
    font-family: ostrich-reg;
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

There's really not much there, not much room for error, so I thought it was my file. I got the file from Font Squirrel, which from what I've heard is a pretty reliable source (I've used them several times before myself), but just for fun I ran it through their webfont generator and it still didn't work. Also, I've straight up tried using another file and got the same result (it was another format as well - .0tf). So I've got no idea. Any suggestions?

By the way, I know this won't work on IE, I literally just started making the site today and I'm not too concerned with that yet.

Here's what happens when I try filtering for fonts:
[image: Filtering for Fonts...]

So, as long as I'm doing this right, I'm pretty sure that means the fonts aren't loading. Which is weird, because I'm pretty sure the path is indeed correct... The Fonts folder is in the same folder that the .html file is in, and the fonts are directly in the Fonts folder.

Comment: Are you sure the url is correct? It could be for example:  url('../Fonts/ostrich-regular-webfont.ttf'); depends on your path.

Comment: In your developer tools of your browser look at the network tab and filter by fonts. You should see here if the fonts are getting loaded or not. If not, your path is wrong

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is an issue, but try putting quotes around your `font-family` definition. ex: `font-family: "ostrich-reg";`

Comment: zgood I updated the question with a picture. As long as I'm doing that right, the fonts aren't being loaded, which is... weird.

Comment: Nima, I just tried the .. thing, didn't work. I'm almost positive the path is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this font on one of my project. I used something like this in my CSS file (still I use my all font in this manner only)

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OstrichSansCondensedLight';
    src: url('ostrich-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('ostrich-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('ostrich-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('ostrich-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('ostrich-light-webfont.svg#OstrichSansCondensedLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

But I used .eot, .woff, .ttf, .svg files. And yes it was working on IE8+ because I used `src: url('ostrich-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),`

let me know if you are facing any issue or any font file is missing I can try to find that for you.

Comment: No idea why this worked, I've used the format I had several times before, but thanks!